# Set visible property of MenuItem

Tags: sapui5

I want set `visible` property of MenuItem https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MenuButton/code/MB.view.xml) component but if I write

```
<items>
    <MenuItem text="Edit" icon="sap-icon://edit" visible="true" />
    <MenuItem text="Save" icon="sap-icon://save" visible="false" />
    <MenuItem text="Open" icon="sap-icon://open-folder" />
</items>
```

The result is always all three items visible

EDIT:

release1.40.6 fix the bug 
But I want use the last long-term maintenance release (1.38.x)... I don't see the fix here
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#releasenotes.html

Comment: I think you should register this as an issue on https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Done https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1088

Answer (score 1):

This <s>is</s> was a bug of the framework ([GitHub issue](http://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1088)). The fix is now [available as of UI5 1.38.8](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/6355c1afa596ef46f79cebf32c43c6185166395a).

Comment: I just wanted this as an answered question.